# Are httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json") and httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json") required?

Tags: java, php, android, json

I'm sending JSON data to server from my Android App and I saw in examples that people add:

```
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

I tried to send JSON without that and I received JSON normally on server using:

```
$jsonReceived = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

What is the use of the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the server.  Some servers require these because they give the server information about what you are providing, and what you want in return.  Other servers may ignore these and just make assumptions.

Anyway:

The `Accept` header is used to tell the Server what kind of response you would be happy with.  In this case you're telling the server that you want JSON output, and not say text, or XML or binary junk.

The `Content-Type` header is used to inform the Server what YOU are sending.  In this case you're telling the Server that you're sending JSON data, and not something else.

These headers are there for Servers that support different formats, like XML, binary, text, images, whatever.

A good implementation of a client always provides these headers, and good servers will reject anything they don't understand (including the case without headers).

If you're still unclear, please read the HTTP specification.